# How to setup a SQL database with specific inheritance?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I made an ASP.NET Web API that's hooked up to a SQL Server database. My item types use inheritance, and I can't figure out how to set up the database correctly. Here's my example

```
[Table("Items")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("StoreRoomItems")]
public class StoreRoomItem : Item
{
    public boolean OnSale { get; set; }
}

[Table("StorageItems")]
public class StorageItem : Item
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add a StoreRoomItem (POST request), I get the following error:
`Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Item' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

Is there a better way to be doing this? How do I make it so I can insert a StoreRoomItem as long as there is an Item in the database with the same ID already?

I tried using

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT StoreRoomItem ON
```

but I got an error saying

> Table 'StoreRoomItem' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation.

Comment: If the item already exists in the database with that id key then you need to update the entry already present.

Comment: Microsoft explains it with all examples pretty well - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Comment: What is the code of your POST request?... specifically the actual insert logic?